# Why isn't there a dedicated "Answers" page for StackExchange websites?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, answers

Why doesn't SE gather all the good answers and put them on a dedicated page, and add a lovely **Answers** button on the top? (is that because there's no more space?).

OK, I'd really like to see some well answered questions (especially for stackoverflow), without seaching here or all over the web. Those answers were voted to be valuable and helpful, and are actually references to a specific topic/category. It would be good to have them sorted like...

Highly upvoted answers of

- This week
- This month
- This season
- This year
- All the time
- .
- In *this* tag
- In *this* category
- ...

SE developers must have thought about it, so what's the reason for not having it?

(am I duplicating a question? I don't see a similar one to the right.)

Comment: If you have 10k on any site (or the equivalent for betas), you can [access a list of highly upvoted answers](http://stackoverflow.com/tools?tab=stats) over the past 1/2/7/14/30 days. It doesn't have its own tab for the general audience because no one comes here thinking "Let me read highly upvoted answers that barely answer the question in a language that I know nothing about, but is awesome because it made the front page of HN and r/programming". If you still want to look for such answers, search for `[tagname] is:answer votes:10` and sort by newest

Comment: Nobody told me that~! So that's the strategy to keep people coming. :D And when you get to 10k, someone would tell you that if you'v got 30k, you can view the top answers in the past 3 months. Nah...that ain't right. I mean...c'mon, I just want to learn something... Well, 10k for 30-day top answers sounds miserable to me either.....oh btw, nice username there. :)

Comment: [tagname] is:answer votes: _10_ thanks a lot for the _tip_.

Comment: @user1643156 They did tell you that: The [faq] has a section on reputation (by the way, the highest privilege is actually at 20k, and is editing tag wikis without being reviewed)

Answer (score 2):

This is *kinda* hidden, but... If you poke around the corners of your favorite *tags* a bit, you can find [hot answers](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jquery/hot).

As folks have noted in the comments, there are other ways to access answers ranked purely by *votes*. That said, I don't think this is particularly useful; an answer's score tends to be fairly connected to the popularity of the *question* it's on, and some tags are *vastly* more popular than others; ranking answers without taking these factors into account isn't going to do much good (folks familiar with the 10k tools will testify to the fact that these are pretty hit and miss; you might as well just view the hot *questions*).